# Rails mailer previews not available from spec/mailers/previews

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I would like to be able to preview my emails in the browser.

I am using Rspec and have the following preview setup in spec/mailers/previews:

```rb
# Preview all emails at http://localhost:3000/rails/mailers/employee_mailer
class EmployeeMailerPreview < ActionMailer::Preview
  def welcome
    Notifier.welcome_email(Employee.first)
  end
end
```

When I try to access this I get the following error:

```
AbstractController::ActionNotFound at /rails/mailers/employee_mailer
Mailer preview 'employee_mailer' not found
```

However, when I put the code for the preview inside of tests/mailers/previews
it works.

How can I configure my Rails app to look for the previews inside of spec/mailers/previews?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use

```
config.action_mailer.preview_path = "#{Rails.root}/spec/mailers/previews"
```

in `config/environments/development.rb` to define the path where previews are located.

Comment: I'd put it in `config/development.rb`

Comment: Edited for correct path: `config/environments/development.rb`

Answer (score 5):

Since you're using RSpec, it's expected that you use the `spec` folder.

It that's the case, I'd rather move your file to `spec/mailers/previews/user_mailer_preview.rb`

Answer (score 2):

For me, the solution was to move everything inside

```
myapp/test/mailers/previews/
```

to

```
myapp/spec/mailers/previews/
```

After doing so, the mailer previews were accessible at the usual URL:

http://localhost:3000/rails/mailers

I found this information [here](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/1333#issuecomment-160479779)