# Rails 5 mailer preview with Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, rspec

I can't preview my emails, at http://localhost:3000/rails/mailers/user_mailer

I always get this error: Mailer preview 'user_mailer' not found

spec/previews/user_mailer_preview.rb

```
class UserMailerPreview < ActionMailer::Preview
  def contact_form
    UserMailer.contact_form("john@example.com", "John", "Hello World!")
  end
end
```

I tried to add:

```
config.action_mailer.preview_path = "#{Rails.root}/spec/previews"
```

but it didn't work.

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: I had the same problem and this thread fixed it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39204047/rails-mailer-previews-not-available-from-spec-mailers-previews

Answer (score 6):

Try moving the file to `spec/mailers/previews/user_mailer_preview.rb`.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to change the path in `environments/development.rb` to:

```
config.action_mailer.preview_path = "#{Rails.root}/spec/mailers/previews"
```